# Is ‘’bescherte’’ in this text an adjective or a verb?

Tags: verb

I think it's a verb, but what's the purpose of using ‘’bescheren’’ here? Its meaning always relates to giving gifts. I'm really confused.

One more question: ‘’darin’’ means in this text "like in the school", right?

> Das Schulgeld sorgte für Einnahmen, der Verkauf von Obst, Gemüse, Blumen **bescherte** Umsatz und sollte die Junggärtnerinnen überdies darin schulen, nicht nach dem Einpflanzen mit dem Denken aufzuhören.

Comment: The adjective would be [*bescheuerte*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bescheuert) ;-)

Answer (score 8):

In this case *bescheren* can best be translated into English by *to yield*.
If *bescheren* or the noun *Bescherung* is used in a positve way of giving, it is most of the time related to Christmas. But it can also be used in a negative way, using *gift* ironically like in *Da haben wir die Bescherung* which means *what a mess*.

The *darin* refers to the relative clause following - they should be trained *in* not stopping to think after planting.

Comment: +1. _Nicht nach dem Einpflanzen mit dem Denken aufzuhören_ is an infinitival construction, though, not a relative clause.

Comment: I agree with the noun "Bescherung" referring to Christmas most of the time (even when used ironically?) but I don't think that's true for the verb as well. The example in the question illustrates that it can be used more broadly.

Comment: It may well be a good idea if the gardeners _stop to think_ after planting, but less so if they _stop thinking_.  The former is something like _anhalten, um zu denken_ or maybe _innehalten_,  whereas the latter is _mit dem Denken aufhören_.

Comment: can one say the clause is partitive, and adverbial at that? A mere *beigeordneter Hauptsatz* is not the optimal, but the easiest solution, no question there. Although, *Der Verkauf bescherte Umsatz sollte* would be odd style (usual in e.g. *das Wetter bedingte Chaos*) and transposed, but it might show the underlying idea. *bescherte* can be understood as "fixed" perhaps, depending on etymology, if *Geschir* (of horses etc) is related. *Bescherung* could rather be understood as *decision* (between good and naughty) I'm not sure; Anyhow it undoubtedly influenced this usage of "give", no contest.

Answer (score 6):

"bescherte" is a verb in this sentence, your assumption was right. 
As Volker Landgraf said, mostly "bescheren" is used in context with Christmas, but you can also use it when something has been produced by an action (a nice example I found: Seine Marijuanasucht bescherte ihm Probleme mit der Polizei - His marijuana addiction brought him trouble with the police), or when someone gives/gifts something to somebody else. When used in a positive context, like the sentence you posted, it actually is meant to be positive. In a negative context, like the marijuana example, it comes with quite the sarcastic undertone.

"darin" - I believe that one point of misunderstanding has not been addressed: I believe that you translate "schulen" in this sentence as the noun "schools". If I interpret the last part of your question correctly, that is. It does mean "to school/teach someone in something" though. Capital letters are quite critical in the German language ;) 
So "darin" is indeed a reference to what the garderners are schooled in, i.e. not stopping to think after the planting is done.

By the way, there is this amazing online dictionary I'd like to tell you about: 
https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/
It comes with short examples and a ton of links to forum discussions for most words that are difficult, like "bescheren".

Hope I did everything right, that's my first answer on here!

Answer (score 0):

The word 'bescherte' is a verb. It is the time form 'Präteritum' of the verb 'bescheren', which means something like 'grant' or 'bestow' in this context.

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bescheren_beschenken_austeilen